# Why does this text pop to the left in Webkit?

Tags: css, webkit

Maybe somebody has seen this before? When you hover over the "First List" and "Second List" text, the text pops a couple pixels to the left. This only happens in Webkit browsers. Tested in Chrome on Linux and Mac, Safari on Mac, and Android browser. Here's the code. I also made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XzVLt

```
#navigation {
    line-height:30px;
    height:30px;
    clear:left;
    text-align:left;
    position:relative;
}

#navigation li {
    padding:0 5px;
    margin-left:-1px;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
}

#navigation ul ul {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
}

#navigation li ul {
    margin-left:-5px;
    padding-right:10px;
}

#navigation li ul li {
    margin-right:-2px;
    text-align:left;
    line-height:15px;
    padding:5px;
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
}

#navigation ul li {
    list-style:none;
}

#navigation ul li {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
}

#navigation li ul {
    display:none;
}

#navigation li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}

#navigation a {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

#navigation li li a {
    display:block;
    margin-left:10px;
    text-indent:-10px;
}
​

<div id="navigation">
<ul>
    <li>
        First list
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        Second list
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that it has something to do with your margins and padding that comes into play as soon as you change the drop-down from display:none to display:block

I use the suckerfish method for drop-downs; you can easily implement this in your method as well. Just change how you phase in the drop-down content as follows:

Replace ...

```
#navigation li ul {
    display:none;
}

#navigation li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

... with ...

```
#navigation li ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:-999em;
}

#navigation li:hover ul {
    left:auto;
}
```

Quick tests in Firefox and Safari - it works just fine ... you'll need some JS to create an element to replace the li:hover pseudo or it won't work in IE.

Read more about the method here http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/

Comment: Thanks! This looks great! You saved me a lot of time and frustration.